# List.contains not working with a column as second argument in Power query M

Tags: list, powerbi, powerquery

Gives F for everything as far as I can see when there are common values in columns A and B

each if List.Contains(List.RemoveNulls( { [A] } ),[B]) = true then "T" else "F"

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please add more information to this question, sample data and/or some screenshots are a great way to make your question clear to others.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Put a T next to each row in Column A when it matches any row of column B? Put a T next to each row in Column B when it matches any row of column A?  Another variant?

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, to check if each row's value in column **a** matches column **b** in any row

add column .. custom column.. with formula

```
= if List.Contains(PriorStepNameHere[b],[a]) then "T" else "F"
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for but I am dealing with a large table (just over 1 million data points) so it took a very long time to run, ended up using some python to transform instead which was quicker. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Sounds good. Try with List.Buffer around the [a]